# Displaying an external file in PHP using a Tag

Tags: php, path, tags

I have a website where I want to display a number of different file types in the same peice of PHP code, but displaying `.txt` or `.php` files is proving a little difficult. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$display_files = "

    <div class=\"fileHoler\">
        <img src=\"path/to/image-file\" />
    </div>
    <div class=\"fileHoler\">
        <video width=\"460\" height=\"auto\" controls>
            <source src=\"path/to/video-file\">
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class=\"fileHoler\">
        path/to/text-file or path/to/php-file // How can I show the file>???
    </div>

";
?>
<?php echo $display_files; ?>
```

This displays the Image and Video files perfectly because of the `<img>` and `<video>` tags, but is there anything I can use to display a txt or php file with a similar method?

Comment: If you just want the contents: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: You might want to use the `iframe` tag. But that will parse it... I don't really understand what of those files you want to show, especially the php one.

Comment: @Zeke Basically, in the TXT or PHP file will contain plain text or embedded code snippets form social media sites. Stuff that can't be categorised as a specific thing, like a video, photo or audio file.

Comment: `<div class="fileHoler">
        <?php readfile(path/to/text-file); ?>
</div>`

Comment: Ok, there's a lot more to this if you're planning on updating your site with a snippet, because that usually comes along with a script and if you load it twice, that will create an issue... but if that's the case and all you want to do is copy and paste the plain text of those files (remember PHP will parse), then @jeroen is right, play with `file_get_contents()`.